# Slideshow works locally but gives errors when online

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I want to make use of this slideshow as it uses a hardcoded nav, I couldn't figure out a better approach to do what [I needed it to do](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-an-auto-scrolling-slideshow-that-works-with-and-without-javascript/)

Got it working easily locally, all good. Then uploaded it and it's not working at all, but giving this error in firebug console. 'TypeError: $(...).cycle is not a function.'

Everything is exactly the same yet I get this error only from the live version which is [here](http://vurtmedia.net/logix-test/index.html).

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: we need a copy of your working code to really help. It seems likely to me that your online version doesn't have access to the referenced files, like jQuery or others.

Comment: Is this the code you mean?
[link](http://vurtmedia.net/logix-test/js/slideshow.js) 
I've tried using the full url to the files as well as I thought it might be that the files are not being referenced, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: It appears that the cycle plugin is not being loaded. I've tried using the standard link 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js">` instead and it still doesn't work, but only online! I've even tried on another domain and the same happens!

Comment: You probably can't load javascript from another site than the site it is being used on. Why don't you try downloading and putting that cycle plugin onto your own site and referencing it there, for example <script type="text/javascript" src="http://vurtmedia.net/logix-test/js/jquery.cycle.all.js">

Comment: Turns out moving the reference from the head to the bottom of the page fixed it, must have been a conflict or something? I'm using html5 boilerplate so there are already links to js files at the bottom of the page - placing the references under there fixed it. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You were probably trying to use the library before it was loaded or loading the js in the wrong order then...